# How do you prove linear independence of functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking a linear algebra course and I'm having trouble proving linear (in)dependence of functions. I understand that I have to prove that the $a_1f(x) + a_2g(x) = 0$ but I don't know how to actually do that. For example given a pair of functions 1 and t, how do you prove linear independence?

Comment: Do you realize that the right-hand side is the $0$ function?  The equation has to be true for all $x$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we don't *prove* $a_1f(x) + a_2g(x) = 0.$  We *assume* that and then prove that $a_1=a_2=0.$

Since functions are defined by their values, one way you can do this is to choose certain $x$-values at which we evaluate the functions.  Each $x$-value gives another equation with the two unknowns $a_1, a_2$ so it should suffice to choose two values of $x$

In your particular example choosing $t=0$ and $t=1$ gives $$a_1=0 \\ a_1 + a_2 = 0$$ which we solve to get $a_1=a_2=0$ which finishes the proof.

Comment: So how does this guarantee that $a_1$ and $a_2$ must equal 0? I understand how this works for the values $t=0$ and $t=1$, but couldn't there be other values where $a_1$ and $a_2$ don't have to be 0?

Comment: @ahzired The values of $a_1, a_2$ are constant by assumption, so they don't depend on the choices we make for $x$ or $t$.  It _is_ possible that for some unlucky choice of $x$ we might not be able to prove that $a_1=a_2=0$ is the only solution, but then we should just choose another $x$-value.

Comment: As a consequence of this fact that we might have chosen the wrong $x$-values, this method can only be used to conclude the functions are linearly independent.  It can't be used to prove the functions are linearly _dependent_ except in fairly special circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

With polynomials, or functions in general, you can evaluate them at certain points and explore the consequences.

For instance, suppose that there exist scalars $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot t = 0$ as functions.  This means the equation holds for all $t$.  Evaluating at $t=0$ gives $a_1 = 0$.  Evaluating at $t=1$ gives $a_1 + a_2 =0$, but since $a_1 =0$ is already known, $a_2 = 0$ as well.  Therefore $1$ and $t$ are linearly independent.